# How to get information when posts with certain keywords are made within a website?

Tags: web-apps, web

Say there are websites example1.com, example2.com, example3.com. Whenever a keyword "keyword1" is posted on example1.com, I need an update to my email(or whatever eg: discord, twitter, facebook).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what's not clear?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. So what exactly you are looking for: a library (for what environment?), a module/extension (for what framework?) – or something else?

Answer (score 0):

For highly specific queries, you can build your own modular system consisting of a crawler, indexer and email notifier. If you don't want to build your own crawler you can use any search engine of your choice, and query their index periodically.
I think sending your own reports (frequency, length, formatting...) will remain your own responsibility.

If you want to search some *news-sites* about some topic, once there was Google News Alerts. Whenever some newspaper/newssite (that doesn't mind being crawled by G.) publishes a new article with a certain keyword, Google will send you mail with  a source link and some preview textsnippet.

To a certain extent this is still possible with [news.google.com](https://news.google.com/) .

In the desktop view, click on "Search for topics, locations and sources", and save your search.
However I think they have removed the email notification part (maybe they have replaced it with optional smartphone notifications)

Answer (score 0):

The question is very vague. Various websites present various data in many different ways - some have APIs, some have RSS that you could utilize, other output HTML that can be scraped problemlessly, different ones may require e.g. authenticating to access a certain page.

You also haven't mentioned what kind of software you're looking for. A Windows application that would run in background and do it for you after an easy setup? A Linux-compatible executable that you can set up and run on some server or in Docker? Or perhaps a programming library or framework that would help you to write your own application?

In my opinion the question is unanswerable accurately without knowing these details, but a generic response that would cover most use cases is to use a library like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) in combination with some SMTP/Discord/Twitter/Facebook library, write a fitting code for your use case and run it every X seconds on a server.